# When .onChange Picker modifier is called

Tags: swift, swiftui, onchange

I have following `Picker` in my SwiftUI `ContentView`:

```
Picker("", selection: $approxType, content: {
    Text("Linear").tag(1)
    Text("Quadratic").tag(2)
    Text("Exponential").tag(3)
})
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
.frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
.onChange(of: approxType, perform: { value in
    calculated = false
})
```

and I'm wondering when `onChange` modifier is performed. Well, it seems that ContentView is refreshed first and only then onChange closure is performed. What I need is to ensure that @State var `calculated` is set to `false` prior ContentView is refreshed. I appreciate any hint.

Comment: Changing the Picker selection should not force refresh your entire ContentView. I would guess there's an issue with the way 'calculated' is connected to something else in your view? If you put test this code separately, it performs correctly.

Comment: You should not rely on order of changed states - only react on them.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the question but maybe you are looking for `.onAppear`

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is to ensure that @State var "calculated" is set to false prior ContentView is refreshed

You can just set it to false when it's initialised:

```
@State private var calculated = false
```

---

However, if you want the same behaviour as `onChange` but also on the first refresh on your view, you can use `onReceive` instead of `onChange`:

```
.onReceive(Just(approxType)) { approxType in
    calculated = false
}
```

Note: for `Just` to work, you need to `import Combine` first.